# Tuneup pro virus opening its own searchtab, how to remove without formatting

Tags: windows-7, firefox, virus

Ok, I have had it with this bastard. I have tried everything free you can get a hold of but I can't get rid of it.

I know the best way to get rid of it would be to format the computer, but!

A) My mind is dang set on removing it without doing that.

B) At this point it's reasonable to worry that the mo-fo will be backed up with everything else, so if possible I'd rather not wipe my computer.

**The symptoms of the virus:**
Whenever I've been idling a litte, if browser is closed, it will open the browser (firefox) and open a new tab, if browser is open it only opens a new tab, and this tab searches for words like "brother" or "camera" (all innocent random words) that then re-directs to a scam site that usually has to do with Tune-up pro, but *"you're the winner! Click me to claim your price"* sites have also appeared.

**OS:** Win 7 (64x)

What I've done:

- Run my anti-virus program a bunchload of times, with the most recent updates and the thuroughest search-options
- Run spybot search and destroy
- Run other safe spyware/virus removal programs
- Removed all addons in firefox
- Reinstalled firefox
- Uninstalled all programs I don't know what they do through the control panels's uninstall option.

As far as I know, I've done everything I could find on google yet the bugger persist, and just now opened up my browser to show me its stupid ads.

Is there anything else I could do without re-installing windows?

Comment: [Remove TuneUpPro.com pop-up ads (Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/tuneuppro-com-removal/) is a step by step removal guide.

Comment: I tried it prior to this, didn't find anything. :(

Comment: System Restore?

Comment: The last system restore point ought to be when I bought the computer 2 years ago, I will wait and see if there are any other options, then I'll try this before formatting. Thank you.

Comment: There should be system restore points created by Windows Update ...

Comment: I don't do windows update, last one I did was on win XP 6 years ago :') (Which may or may not be why I got this thing in the first place since I really don't install any strange programs at all)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the remains of tuneup pro files that keeps harassing you. Try show all hidden files, as it may set its files as invisible to protect itself (you can hide all system files afterwards), search for its folder and files in program files. Then, back up registry files, use the Find function in registry editor to find items of tuneup pro, and delete them all. That's what I usually do when I notice some rubbish comes inside. Also, check DNS settings, proxy settings and hosts file, this vicious thing may change that, too. This will surely help:[get rid of tuneup pro ads](http://blog.doohelp.com/how-to-get-rid-ofremove-tuneup-pro-ads-virus-removal-tips/)

Comment: I have never installed that program and the symptoms described in the link are different from what I have; nothing is in the autostart folder but the programs I know and want there. The tip on searching the systems files manually are one of the things I haven't tried (I've run a program of windows that were supposed to remove everything not windows with no luck though). I will try that.